# ForeignCollection throws SQLException on iterating using streams

Tags: java, database, orm, ormlite

I have three entity classes: `PlayerData`, `IpData`, and `TwinData`.
Both `TwinData` and `IpData` refer to `PlayerData` with a foreign key.

Here is the code:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class PlayerData {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField
    private UUID uuid;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<IpData> ips;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<TwinData> twins;

    // Getters and setters...
}

@DatabaseTable
public class IpData {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private PlayerData playerData;

    @DatabaseField
    private Date firstUsage;

    @DatabaseField
    private String address;

    // Getters and setters...
}

@DatabaseTable
public class TwinData {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private PlayerData mainPlayer;

    @DatabaseField
    private boolean adminNoticed;

    @DatabaseField
    private UUID uuid;

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

When I try to iterate over `PlayerData.ips` with streams, I get SQLException `[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: playerData_id)`. Tables are auto-generated with `TableUtils.createIfNotExists()`.

This is the code that throws that exception:

```
// playerData is retrieved from Dao<PlayerData, Integer>
playerData.getIps().stream().noneMatch(ip -> ip.getAddress().equals(playerIp))
```

I just don't really get why it attempts to select `playerData_id` column.
Should I manually create database tables for `TwinData` and `IpData` with `playerData_id` column? Haven't tried this yet, but I don't think it would help.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to iterate over `PlayerData.ips` with streams, I get `SQLException`[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: `playerData_id`). Tables are auto-generated with `TableUtils.createIfNotExists()`.

You will get that error if `playerData_id` is not a field in the table.  I'm surprised that `TableUtils.createIfNotExists()` did not create a field `playerData_id` in the `IpData` table.  I suspect that the tables existed already and you are not using ORMLite generated schema.

By default when ORMLite sees a `foreign = true` field, it will store the id of that type in the entity in question.  See the [foreign fields documentation](https://ormlite.com/docs/foreign).  If your schema is defining the relationship between the entities differently, for example with another table to define the relationship, then you will need to setup that entity by yourself and query it using the DAO for that entity.

You maybe should look at the [foreign object example](http://ormlite.com/docs/example-foreign) for more information.

Hope this helps.